# CRT for linear forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra

Suppose $A,B,C,A',B',C'$ are *random* distinct primes in $[T,2T]$ and $u,v$ are integers in $[T,2T]$.

Suppose we know:

$$Au+Bv\equiv r\bmod C$$
$$A'u+B'v\equiv r'\bmod C'$$

can we identify $u,v$ in polynomial time **without** integer linear programming?

Assume unique solution exists.

Note because of polynomial time algorithm for fixed dimension integer linear programming a polynomial time algorithm for the problem exists. I want to avoid it.

Comment: Are you sure that the conditions even guarantee a unique u/v pair?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, doesn't distinctness+primality mean that the solution is determined modulo $C C' \ge T^2$, which, assuming $T > 1$, is strictly bigger than $T$?

Comment: @LSpice I don't think you can run the usual matrix methods since you can't necessarily take inverses mod $CC'$ and in fact the various terms that you're going to be working with ($AC'$, etc.) are all non-invertible mod $CC'$.

Comment: Actually, a very simple (counter)example: consider $u-2v=1 \bmod 5$ and $u-4v=1\bmod 7$. Then $(0, 2)$ and $(1, 0)$ are solutions to both.

Comment: It comes from a system which guarantees unique solution.